# Google Maps SDK Error started popping on last hour

Tags: android, google-maps

```
:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201216046@20.12.16 (040306-0) line 9
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.ct.<init>
```

This error started happening on random devices. Does anyone have the same issue?

I didn't release anything, didn't change anything about the app.

My map fragment XML:

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/map_stops" 
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.comprovei.entregas.fragments.TabTripsMapFragment" />
```

The fragment code:

```
public class TabTripsMapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_stops_map, null, false);

        ChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map_stops);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {

        ...

    }

}
```

edit*: I'm trying to follow this up on Twitter:
https://twitter.com/googlemaps/status/1253419390046834691

edit:
**FINAL RESPONSE HERE:** https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154855417#comment509

Comment: Same, seems to be across play services versions as well.

Comment: Does anyone know where is the official forum for us to report this issue?

Comment: According to Google, _this is_ the official forum.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154820090

Comment: Google is providing updates here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154855417

Comment: Not to self... remove Google Maps from any safety critical application that I write.

Comment: It's a internal error in Google Maps API, there is nothing we can do. We should just wait.

Comment: Someone found a possible workaround, clearing the storage, it worked for me. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154855417#comment135

Comment: Clear data on app works.

Answer (score 25):

All apps are crashing except Google Maps application itself.

Maps-first applications are totally useless right now..

There is nothing we can do. We should just wait.

this is being tracked by google here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154855417

Answer (score 8):

Google Maps is aware of the issue and working on a fix ([link](https://twitter.com/JStheoriginal/status/1253415465243697161?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Eembeddedtimeline%7Ctwterm%5Eprofile%3Agooglemaps&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Foutage.report%2Fgoogle-maps)):

[image: Google confirms outage]

Answer (score 6):

**Update:its fixed now.Clear data strorage of app and then open app**

API is partially down right now, affecting many apps esp. delivery services that use its SDK, causing mobile apps to crash all over the world.Even App like Uber is also crashed

Comment: Clearing apps's data is not the solution. It will remove everything from the app and how we supposed to inform our more than 100,000 active users to go to settings and clear the app's data? more than half of them wont even know what is app's data.

Comment: its only for for users who opened app in that timeframe when google map was down,otherwise who didnot open app in that specific timeframe are not facing any problem