# AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: androidmapsapi-ZoomTableManager

Tags: android, ios, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-maps-android-api-3

My app that uses Google Maps SDK (v2) just started crashing with this exception:

```
Process: com.currentlocation.android, PID: 7328
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=12
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.ct.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201216081@20.12.16 (120400-0):9)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.cv.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201216081@20.12.16 (120400-0):23)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.util.m.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201216081@20.12.16 (120400-0):14)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

In the v3 beta SDK, the stack trace is:

```
2020-04-23 15:59:06.064 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example, PID: 22717
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=12
        at com.google.android.libraries.maps.bv.zzbs.<init>(ZoomTable.java:24)
        at com.google.android.libraries.maps.bv.zzbv.zza(ZoomTableQuadTree.java:57)
        at com.google.android.libraries.maps.br.zzd.zza(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.libraries.maps.hi.zzas.zza(Suppliers.java:7)
        at com.google.android.libraries.maps.br.zza.zzh(SharedMapComponentImpl.java:58)
        at com.google.android.libraries.maps.gu.zzat.zza(RendererFactoryImpl.java:88)
        at com.google.android.libraries.maps.it.zzav.zza(GoogleMapImpl.java:59)
        at com.google.android.libraries.maps.it.zzci.zza(MapFragmentDelegateImpl.java:3)
        at com.google.android.libraries.maps.it.zzcg.zza(MapFragmentDelegateImpl.java:15)
        at com.google.android.libraries.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(SupportMapFragment.java:15)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zae.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:9)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:25)
        at com.google.android.libraries.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(SupportMapFragment.java:34)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:310)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1185)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1354)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1432)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1495)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2617)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2569)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2722)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.activityCreated(FragmentStateManager.java:336)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1186)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2222)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1995)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1951)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1847)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2621)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2569)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2722)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.activityCreated(FragmentStateManager.java:336)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1186)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1354)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1432)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1495)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2617)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2569)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:247)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:541)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1432)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7848)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3294)
2020-04-23 15:59:06.064 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

What is the cause?

Comment: Maybe it's Google Maps problem

Comment: Is this a production app or just a test?

Comment: Same. Production environment and the app is a critical mission. This is stopping the operations of many customers.

Comment: Same here! Before getting this `error` I got another one saying that the `Google Maps Api` cannot connect to the servers. Probably issue from them

Comment: **Note: Do not post "me too" answers to this question.** Only answers which answer the question should be posted as answers.

Comment: updates will be here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154855417

Comment: Related: [Google Maps SDK Error started popping on last hour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61395654/1364007).

Comment: It's a internal error in Google Maps API, there is nothing we can do. We should just wait.

Comment: While the error is present how to catch it in the code, so the app will not crash and I'll show the message to the user?

Comment: @MidnightGuest If you expand on that a bit, it could make a good question.

Comment: The only option available now is to "Wait for few hours" until it's fixed

Comment: From Google: Update: We have identified a possible root cause for the crash and are undoing the change. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154855417#comment58

Comment: My app is working now and loading Google Maps fine.

Comment: Looks like the issue is fixed but I had to clear the app cache in the app settings.

Comment: as @DroidDev said clear app Storage and Cache it will work.( it works for me right now). but not sure if google maps fixed it or not.

Comment: Please refer to issuetracker.google.com/154855417#comment421

Answer (score 100):

**Edit**: following is the official solution from Google ([link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154855417#comment509))

### **Summary**

Google Maps SDK thread crashes App (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) - Solution Offered

### **Description**

On **April 23 2020 starting at 11:30 PDT**, Google served for 4 hours an update to the configuration of a Maps mobile component, triggering crashes in Maps SDKs for Android and iOS. Applications on devices that downloaded this version of the configuration (during the outage period) were vulnerable to the crash. Workaround solutions are offered for Maps SDKs for Android and iOS.

### **Maps SDK for Android**

**Maps SDK for Android v2 (included in Google Play Services)**

The updates to Google Play Services to fix the crash has been published to all devices with Google Play Services version 17.4.55 and newer. There is no change to the version number of Google Play Services on the device after the update is installed. No action is required from developers or end users to receive the updated Maps module; however, developers can verify that the module is present on a given device with the following adb command:

```
adb shell dumpsys activity provider com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.GmsModuleProvider
```

You should see the line `Module Set ID: maps` listed in the `Module Sets` section.

```
Module Set ID: maps, Module Set Version: 2015120015120000
```

The crash rates of Maps SDK for Android v2 are back to normal.

As of now, if you have not updated your app with the client-side code workarounds mentioned below, you do not need to take further action.

If you have already updated your app with the workarounds, you can remove the workaround in a subsequent update of your app (but keeping the workaround is safe).

**Premium Plan Maps SDK for Android v2 or Maps SDK for Android v3 beta (static libraries)**

If your app uses the Premium Plan Maps SDK for Android v2 or Maps SDK for Android v3 beta (static libraries), and is still experiencing crashes, we still highly recommend you to roll out the workarounds below via an update to your app. As your application is loading a static version of the SDK which is vulnerable to the bad data being stored on some devices, only an update to your application can solve the problem.

**Play Store review approvals**

If you update your app but experience Play Store review approvals delays, please file a support case with your app’s Package ID: ⁠[Contact the support team](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/support#contact-maps-support). Our Support Team will internally escalate your request and expedite the approval.

**Negative reviews in the Google Play Store**

Some application developers inquired about 1-star reviews in the Google Play Store left by end-users due to crashes. Only comments that violate Google Play's policy [ 1 ] can be removed. You can also flag abusive reviews in the Play Console [ 2 ]. Applications will not be automatically removed from the Google Play store due to negative reviews. It's also worth noting that the calculation of your overall app review rating favors recent reviews, which means that your rating will recover to pre-incident levels over time.

[ 1 ] ⁠[Ratings & Review on the Play Store](https://play.google.com/about/comment-posting-policy/)

[ 2 ] ⁠[Report inappropriate reviews](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7318385)

### **Maps SDK for iOS**

Crash rates on iOS are back to normal. If your application is still experiencing crashes, you need to update and publish your app with the code workarounds communicated here.

For questions about deploying or expediting your application in the Apple App Store, please contact Apple directly.

---

***With this update, we are closing this issue. Thank you to everyone for your patience. Our team is performing an in-depth internal investigation of this incident; as soon as possible, we will publish our analysis (in approximately a week). In the meantime, if you have any questions, or are still experiencing problems, please ⁠[file a support case](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/support#contact-maps-support).***

### **Workarounds:**

- End users on Android can clear the affected app's data (not just the
  cache).
- End users on iOS can uninstall then reinstall the affected app(s).
- App Developers can apply the code workarounds below in order to solve
  the issue for all their end users.

**Code workaround for iOS:**

Recommended placement for the code is before GMSServices initialization in the application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) (Swift) or application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (Objective-C) method. Specifically:

**Swift:**

```
let key = "GoogleMapsServerControlledParamsKey_bug_154855417"
if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: key) {
    let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    if urls.count > 0 {
        let paramUrl = urls[0].appendingPathComponent("com.google.GoogleMaps/ServerControlledParams", isDirectory: false)
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: paramUrl)
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: key)
}
```

**Objective-C:**

```
NSString *key = @"GoogleMapsServerControlledParamsKey_bug_154855417";
BOOL keyExists = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:key];
if (!keyExists) {
    NSArray<NSURL *> *array =
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory
                                               inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
    if (array.count > 0) {
        NSURL *url =
            [array[0] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"com.google.GoogleMaps/ServerControlledParams"
                                      isDirectory:NO];
        if (url) {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:url error:NULL];
        }
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:key];
}
```

**Code workaround for Android:**

The recommended placement for the code is in Application.onCreate():

**Java**

```
try {
  SharedPreferences hasFixedGoogleBug154855417 = getSharedPreferences("google_bug_154855417", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  if (!hasFixedGoogleBug154855417.contains("fixed")) {
    File corruptedZoomTables = new File(getFilesDir(), "ZoomTables.data");
    File corruptedSavedClientParameters = new File(getFilesDir(), "SavedClientParameters.data.cs");
    File corruptedClientParametersData =
        new File(
          getFilesDir(),
          "DATA_ServerControlledParametersManager.data."
              + getBaseContext().getPackageName());
    File corruptedClientParametersDataV1 =
        new File(
          getFilesDir(),
          "DATA_ServerControlledParametersManager.data.v1."
              + getBaseContext().getPackageName());
    corruptedZoomTables.delete();
    corruptedSavedClientParameters.delete();
    corruptedClientParametersData.delete();
    corruptedClientParametersDataV1.delete();
    hasFixedGoogleBug154855417.edit().putBoolean("fixed", true).apply();
  }
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

**Kotlin**

```
try {
    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("google_bug_154855417", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    if (!sharedPreferences.contains("fixed")) {
        val corruptedZoomTables = File(filesDir, "ZoomTables.data")
        val corruptedSavedClientParameters = File(filesDir, "SavedClientParameters.data.cs")
        val corruptedClientParametersData = File(filesDir, "DATA_ServerControlledParametersManager.data.${packageName}")
        val corruptedClientParametersDataV1 = File(filesDir, "DATA_ServerControlledParametersManager.data.v1.${packageName}")
        corruptedZoomTables.delete()
        corruptedSavedClientParameters.delete()
        corruptedClientParametersData.delete()
        corruptedClientParametersDataV1.delete()
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("fixed", true).apply()
    }
} catch (exception: Exception) {

}
```

The workarounds provided here covers all available flavors and versions of our SDKs for Android. To clarify further (in case you released an earlier version of the workaround that did not delete as many files):

- Applications that use Maps Android SDK v2 should only need to delete
  one file: ZoomTables.data.
- Applications that use Maps Android SDK v3 beta should only need to
  delete one file, either

  DATA_ServerControlledParametersManager.data.v1. +
                 getBaseContext().getPackageName())
  or

  DATA_ServerControlledParametersManager.data. +
             getBaseContext().getPackageName())

Comment: Our app works on the emulator, same code, but not on a production device. It started happening while zooming. FATAL EXCEPTION: androidmapsapi-ZoomTableManager

Comment: well, google's maps app works on android and doesn't on iOS at the moment.

Comment: Just checked many apps using Map are crashing, including Uber, Lyft, etc. Google Maps seems to work for me, it must be pointing to another API endpoint different from public API.

Comment: For me Google Map app works fine, just my android app which uses google map sdk doesn't work.

Comment: The real crime here is that even when the maps call is encapsulated in a try / catch statement, somehow Google Maps supercedes your try call and crashes the app instead of throwing an error. Maps should throw a proper exception when it's not available, not just crash everything.

Comment: same problem in Pakistan

Comment: Its solved for me, I must delete app storage, but Uber app was auto solved.

Comment: Would you rather have the actual bug report instead of a link to a twitter post?  Here you go: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154855417.

Answer (score 50):

Seems in every app Google Map creates ZoomTables.data file.

[image]

This file was malformed, malformed version of it that could be downloaded from [comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154855417#comment205).
To reproduce the issue remove ZoomTables.data from the app packages on the device and insert malformed one. The app should crash.

Currently, the issue was solved on google's side, but the apps still contain a cached version of that data file.
To fix the issue we should remove that file right on the app start in Application onCreate Method.

```
private void fixGoogleMapBug() {
  try {
    SharedPreferences hasFixedGoogleBug154855417 = getSharedPreferences("google_bug_154855417", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (!hasFixedGoogleBug154855417.contains("fixed")) {
      File corruptedZoomTables = new File(getFilesDir(), "ZoomTables.data");
      File corruptedSavedClientParameters = new File(getFilesDir(), "SavedClientParameters.data.cs");
      File corruptedClientParametersData =
          new File(
            getFilesDir(),
            "DATA_ServerControlledParametersManager.data."
                + getBaseContext().getPackageName());
      File corruptedClientParametersDataV1 =
          new File(
            getFilesDir(),
            "DATA_ServerControlledParametersManager.data.v1."
                + getBaseContext().getPackageName());
      corruptedZoomTables.delete();
      corruptedSavedClientParameters.delete();
      corruptedClientParametersData.delete();
      corruptedClientParametersDataV1.delete();
      hasFixedGoogleBug154855417.edit().putBoolean("fixed", true).apply();
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {

  }
}
```

**Update 1**

I've updated workaround, base on the latest google developers [comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154855417#comment509):

> The workarounds provided here covers all available flavors and versions of our SDKs for Android. To clarify further (in case you released an earlier version of the workaround that did not delete as many files):
>
> Applications that use Maps Android SDK v2 should only need to delete one file: ZoomTables.data.
> Applications that use Maps Android SDK v3 beta should only need to delete one file, either DATA_ServerControlledParametersManager.data.v1. + getBaseContext().getPackageName()) or DATA_ServerControlledParametersManager.data. + getBaseContext().getPackageName())

Comment: Excluding ZoomTables.data file worked for me. Thanks a lot! Everyone should use this and mark as answer!

Comment: @ArthurAttout Yes, I rather do this for now and fix my production apps that are more than 16 hours crashed than waiting more time for Google's fix

Comment: @EduardoHerzer Google's ETA is 48 hours and production full roll out will take more than 48 hours. (Update review time + roll out time)

Comment: This worked for me! I only changed a little for my Flutter app: 
var dir = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
File corruptedZoomTables = new File(dir.path + "/ZoomTables.data");

Comment: Why do we remove the ZoomTables.data just once? What if this gets corrupted in the future again?

Comment: New oficial workaround from google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154855417#comment465. Please update the answer

Answer (score 14):

This solution worked for me

1. First open "App Info"
2. Choose "Storage"
3. Click "Clear data"
4. Open app again and check if the issue fixed.

   Below are suggestions just to help your customers.
5. Send an email to your all users for the inconvenience and describe them the issue they faced and give them above mentioned steps to resolve their issue.
6. You can also send Push Notification to all your users with Firebase Push Notifications, if your app have the push notifications service.

Screenshots demonstration:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: OP is trying to understand what caused this so they can solve it permanently, not solve it on their own phone until the next incidence. Deleting state from the device destroys the very data necessary to debug this issue.

Answer (score 10):

### Solution Offered for iOS & Android:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154855417#comment509

### Maps SDK for Android v2 (included in Google Play Services)

> The updates to Google Play Services to fix the crash has been published to all devices with Google Play Services version 17.4.55 and newer. There is no change to the version number of Google Play Services on the device after the update is installed. No action is required from developers or end users to receive the updated Maps module; however, developers can verify that the module is present on a given device with the following adb command:

```
adb shell dumpsys activity provider com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.GmsModuleProvider
```

You should see the line `Module Set ID: maps` listed in the `Module Sets` section.

```
Module Set ID: maps, Module Set Version: 2015120015120000
```

> The crash rates of Maps SDK for Android v2 are back to normal.
>
> As of now, if you have not updated your app with the client-side code
>   workarounds mentioned below, you do not need to take further action.
>
> If you have already updated your app with the workarounds, you can
>   remove the workaround in a subsequent update of your app (but keeping
>   the workaround is safe).

---

### Code workaround for Android:

The productive version was fixed (on google's side) but if you still have problems with your emulator you have to run the following code only once.

> The recommended placement for the code is in Application.onCreate():

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    fixGoogleMapBugTemp()   //TODO: Then clean this line

//  ...  

}

/**
 * Observation: Invoke this method only once
 */
private fun fixGoogleMapBugTemp() {
    val googleBug = getSharedPreferences("google_bug_154855417", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    if (!googleBug.contains("fixed")) {
        val corruptedZoomTables = File(filesDir, "ZoomTables.data");
        corruptedZoomTables.delete();
        googleBug.edit().putBoolean("fixed", true).apply();
    }
}
```

**Workaround**: Clear application data (not just the cache).

**Note**: A copy of the [problematic file](https://issuetracker.google.com/action/issues/154855417/attachments/29614802?download=true) from the app packages on the device if anyone needs it for repro.

[image: Block]

[Source](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154855417)

GL

Answer (score 10):

Drawbacks of solutions above:

- ZoomTables.data is deleted on every device, regardless of whether the device is affected by the crash or not
- Workaround only works once, is it sure that this problem never happens again?

Drawbacks of my solution:

- on first execution of maps activity on affected device map is empty. After rotation of device or second execution map is shown up

My solution catches the Exception thrown by the Maps SDK, call this in onCreate of the Application class:

```
public static void catchGoogleMapsException(final Context context)
{
  final Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultHandler =
    Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
  Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(
    (@NonNull final Thread thread, @NonNull final Throwable ex) ->
    {
      if (thread.getName().contains("ZoomTableManager"))
      {
        new File(context.getFilesDir(), "ZoomTables.data").delete();
        Log.w("Maps Bug 154855417", "Caught exception and deleted ZoomTables.data");
      }
      else
        if (defaultHandler!=null)
          defaultHandler.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
        else
          throw new RuntimeException(
            "No default uncaught exception handler.", ex);
    });
}
```

Comment: I have just pushed out a similar workaround.  As I have alternative mapping sources to Google in my App I change the default source not to be Google as well giving the user a message explaining what has been done.  Hopefully it will keep me safe if Google manage to do something similar in the future.  I do expect there testing to improve though.

Comment: I had to clear storage to resolve this issue.  For whatever reason, deleting ZoomTables.data wasn't enough to resolve this for me.

I did the delete in my startup activity onCreate().  I guess I should look into the application scope Exception Handler.

Answer (score 9):

For Android, multiple developers mentioned a workaround consisting in deleting the ZoomTable.data file directly from their application. After review, this fix seems safe, and you could try it in your application.

Please refer to 
https://issuetracker.google.com/154855417#comment179

If you want your users to continue using your app without re-installing,
The sample code is copy-pasted here for your convenience. In **Application.onCreate()**:

```
SharedPreferences googleBug = getSharedPreferences("google_bug_154855417", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if (!googleBug.contains("fixed")) {
        File corruptedZoomTables = new File(getFilesDir(), "ZoomTables.data");
        corruptedZoomTables.delete();
        googleBug.edit().putBoolean("fixed", true).apply();
}
```

reference: [Google Maps SDK is crashing -- partially resolved](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154855417#comment205)

Comment: Please refer to https://issuetracker.google.com/154855417#comment421

Answer (score 7):

Complete & official answer for all :

Diagnosis: Crash of the Google Maps Platform mobile SDKs (iOS & Android) at load.

Workaround: * Clear the affected app's data (not just the cache), or uninstall then reinstall the affected app(s).

- Code workaround for iOS:

Recommended placement for the code is before GMSServices initialization in the application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) (Swift) or application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (Objective-C) method.  Specifically:

## Swift:

```
let key = "GoogleMapsServerControlledParamsKey_bug_154855417"
if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: key) {
    let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    if urls.count > 0 {
        let paramUrl = urls[0].appendingPathComponent("com.google.GoogleMaps/ServerControlledParams", isDirectory: false)
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: paramUrl)
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: key)
}
```

## Objective-C:

```
NSString *key = @"GoogleMapsServerControlledParamsKey_bug_154855417";
BOOL keyExists = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:key];
if (!keyExists) {
    NSArray<NSURL *> *array =
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory
                                               inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
    if (array.count > 0) {
        NSURL *url =
            [array[0] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"com.google.GoogleMaps/ServerControlledParams"
                                      isDirectory:NO];
        if (url) {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:url error:NULL]);
        }
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:key];
}
```

Once you have deployed it in your app, you can file a Maps Support case if you would like us to help expedite its approval. Please make sure to include your application's ID, Bundle ID, and the version you want reviewed in your case.

- Code workaround for Android:

  The recommended placement for the code is in Application.onCreate():

  ## Java

  ```
  try {
    SharedPreferences hasFixedGoogleBug154855417 = getSharedPreferences("google_bug_154855417", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (!hasFixedGoogleBug154855417.contains("fixed")) {
      File corruptedZoomTables = new File(getFilesDir(), "ZoomTables.data");
      File corruptedSavedClientParameters = new File(getFilesDir(), "SavedClientParameters.data.cs");
      File corruptedClientParametersData =
          new File(
            getFilesDir(),
            "DATA_ServerControlledParametersManager.data.v1."
                + getBaseContext().getPackageName());
      corruptedZoomTables.delete();
      corruptedSavedClientParameters.delete();
      corruptedClientParametersData.delete();
      hasFixedGoogleBug154855417.edit().putBoolean("fixed", true).apply();
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {

  }
  ```

  ## Kotlin

  ```
  try {
      val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("google_bug_154855417", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
      if (!sharedPreferences.contains("fixed")) {
          val corruptedZoomTables = File(filesDir, "ZoomTables.data")
          val corruptedSavedClientParameters = File(filesDir, "SavedClientParameters.data.cs")
          val corruptedClientParametersData = File(filesDir, "DATA_ServerControlledParametersManager.data.v1.${packageName}")
          corruptedZoomTables.delete()
          corruptedSavedClientParameters.delete()
          corruptedClientParametersData.delete()
          sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("fixed", true).apply()
      }
  } catch (exception: Exception) {

  }
  ```

Source : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/1548554

Answer (score 4):

You should call the follow method on the onCreate of your Android app to avoid the crash.

```
private fun clearCorruptedGMapsPreference() {
        try {
            val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("google_bug_154855417", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            if (!sharedPreferences.contains("fixed")) {
                val corruptedZoomTables = File(filesDir, "ZoomTables.data")
                val corruptedSavedClientParameters = File(filesDir, "SavedClientParameters.data.cs")
                val corruptedClientParametersData = File(filesDir, "DATA_ServerControlledParametersManager.data.${packageName}")
                val corruptedClientParametersDataV1 = File(filesDir, "DATA_ServerControlledParametersManager.data.v1.${packageName}")
                corruptedZoomTables.delete()
                corruptedSavedClientParameters.delete()
                corruptedClientParametersData.delete()
                corruptedClientParametersDataV1.delete()
                sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("fixed", true).apply()
            }
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            LogUtil.e(this@CourierApplication::class.java.name, "An error has happened. Error: ".plus(exception.cause?.message
                    ?: ""))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is working code for Xamarin. You need to install Xamarin.Essentials nuget package.

```
if (!Preferences.Get("google_bug_fixed", false))
{
    var corruptedZoomTables = new File(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "ZoomTables.data");
    corruptedZoomTables.Delete();
    Preferences.Set("google_bug_fixed", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround suggested will only work one time:**

I suggest to send a silent push notification to your app about Google Map Zoom Data Corrupted or make an API call to check the status of the Google Map Zoom Data. If you think this as un-necessary server call every time, you can either use push notification to trigger this logic or integrate with one of your existing calls where you check status of your servers. Leaving this to your app specific logics.Doing so, if Google Maps again throws this error you can re-trigger your work-around.

If server call, this will reset ZoomData for all your users.
If push-notifications, you can send notifications to some users.

```
fun receivedPushNotificationZoomDataCorrupted() {
 try {
        val corruptedZoomTables = File(filesDir, "ZoomTables.data")
        val corruptedSavedClientParameters = File(filesDir,  "SavedClientParameters.data.cs")
        val corruptedClientParametersData = File(filesDir,    "DATA_ServerControlledParametersManager.data.v1.${packageName}")
        corruptedZoomTables.delete()
        corruptedSavedClientParameters.delete()
        corruptedClientParametersData.delete()
    }
 } catch (exception: Exception) {

 }
}
```