# Google Maps Android SDK Crashing- androidmapsapi-ZoomTableManager

Tags: android, google-maps

Was using the Mock GPS application to test a few things out, but the app started crashing all of a sudden. Tried to find something on the Android Studio logs. Found these logs

```
2020-04-24 02:36:39.538 31343-31415/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: androidmapsapi-ZoomTableManager
Process: com.lexa.fakegps, PID: 31343
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=12
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.ct.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201216081@20.12.16 (120400-0):9)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.cv.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201216081@20.12.16 (120400-0):23)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.util.m.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201216081@20.12.16 (120400-0):14)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Anybody else facing similar issues? I've integrated Maps on a couple of apps of mine too. It's crashing there too. Is there a solution to it?

The Google Maps app on the device works fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: androidmapsapi-ZoomTableManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61396588/androidruntime-fatal-exception-androidmapsapi-zoomtablemanager)

Comment: Yes, we are shutdown.  Looks like Google is aware of this issue. https://twitter.com/googlemaps/status/1253419390046834691

Comment: @jon Came across it but need a solution to it, as of now I'm aware that it's an issue from Google Maps, and the only solution that i am informed of is clear cache. I'm not sure if that's an appropriate solution for apps that have already been deployed.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it's from Google map, the only solution right now is to "Wait"
according to Google Map Team :

Diagnosis: If you see a stack dump starting with the lines:

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=12
         at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.ct.

... you are affected by this error.

Workaround: None at this time

Update: problem fixed, you have to clear the App data and cache

Comment: What about the apps already deployed to mass audience? Isn't there anyway that could be fixed through the Maps SDK from their end?
Do you have any details about the issuetracker link that must've been created for the same?

Comment: @DeepLathia according to Google official update, there is no other solution than clearing the App's Data or rollout an update to the clients, you can send the map team request to speed up the update process, check here : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154855417#comment421