# Google Maps java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Today I found out in Appcenter crashes related to Google Maps.

```
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.ct.<init>
:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201216083@20.12.16 (120408-0), line 9
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=12
```

There is a [discussion on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/g6t8fu/google_maps_sdk_error_started_popping_on_last_hour/) about this issue and it seems like there is a bug in Google Maps.

Is there any workaround for Xamarin until they update Xamarin.Forms.Maps nuget package?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61396588/androidruntime-fatal-exception-androidmapsapi-zoomtablemanager